# Month in c# using DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am wondering if there is way to have the user enter a number like 01 and have that string converted to the month using dateTime.  I know how to have the user enter a string such as 01/01/2011 and have the converted to a DateTime.  Is there a way to use datetime to convert a two number string into a month.  Something like this, but that would work

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please the month numerically");
        string date = Console.ReadLine();
        dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date).Month;
```

Comment: DateTime cannot represent a "naked" month: it also needs a year, a day, an hour, a minute, and so on.

Comment: It's really unclear what you expect the input and output to be here. Suppose the user enters "5" - what would you expect the value of dt to be?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could probably get it jumping through some hoops with DateTime, however;

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(int monthNumber);
```

is probably easier.

Answer (score 2):

It is already built into the .NET framework: see [System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier to just have an array of 12 elements, each being a month.

```
String[] Months = new String[] {"Jan", "Feb"}; //put all months in
Console.WriteLine("Please the month numerically");
string date = Console.ReadLine();
int index = 0;
if (!int.TryParse(date, out index)) {
    // handle error for input not being an int
}
dt = Months[index];
```

If you really wanted to stick with using the DateTime class, you could take in the month and then tag on some day and year and use the method you provided in your code. For example...

```
dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date + "/01/2012").Month;
```

But this is less advised.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not complete, cause you need to specify which `year` and which `day` in the date.

Assuming that that data have to be of the current date, you can do something like this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, int.Parse("01"), DateTime.Now.Day);
```

Don't forget, obviously, add a couple of controls, like

- Month range {1-12}
- Month string is a number

**EDIT**

```
  int month =-1;
  if(int.TryParse(userInputString, out month)){
      if(month>=1 && month <=12) {

           DateTime dt = new DateTime(
                               DateTime.Now.Year, 
                               month, 
                               DateTime.Now.Day);
      }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string ReturnMonthName(string pMonth)
{
    switch (pMonth)
    {
        case "01" :
            return "January";
        case "02":
            return "February";
        case "03":
            return "March";
        case "04":
            return "April";
        case "05":
            return "May";
        case "06":
            return "June";
        case "07":
            return "July";
        case "08":
            return "August";
        case "09":
            return "September";
        case "10":
            return "October";
        case "11":
            return "November";
        case "12":
            return "December";
        default:
            return "Invalid month";
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Strip the month from your datetime and use a switch/case select to assign your variable.

```
        switch (val)
        {
            case 1:
                MessageBox.Show("The day is - Sunday");
                break;
            case 2:
                MessageBox.Show("The day is - Monday");
                break;
            case 3:
                MessageBox.Show("The day is - Tuesday");
                break;
            case 4:
                MessageBox.Show("The day is - wednesday");
                break;
            case 5:
                MessageBox.Show("The day is - Thursday");
                break;
            case 6:
                MessageBox.Show("The day is - Friday");
                break;
            case 7:
                MessageBox.Show("The day is - Saturday");
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Out of range !!");
                break;
        }
```